# django rest framework serializer usage

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I want to return some json data to client. Hence I write a serializer to represent the domain object to output at the end. I quite cannot understand the mechanism under the hood, also the nested serializers. Take below model as example:

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    address = serializers.CharField()
    zipcode = serializers.CharField()

class AccountSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    address = AddressSerializer
```

According to official document, I know I can initial AccountSerializer by

```
ac = AccountSerializer(data={"name":"TOM"})
```

**Question 1**

If I want to initial AccountSerializer in the some way as below:

```
ac = AccountSerializer()
ac.name = "TOM"
```

How I can do that?

**Question 2**

How to make the below code works?

```
ad = AddressSerializer(data={"address":"NewYork"});
ac = AccountSerializer(data={"name":"TOM"});
ac.address = ad
ac.is_valid()
ac.data
```

So that I can get the output like

```
{name: "Tom", address: {address: "NewYork"}}
```

Thanks so much if any teach/comment from you.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

```
data = {
    'name': 'TOM'
}
ac = AccountSerializer(data=data)
```

**Question 2**

Should be something like:

```
data = {
    'name': 'TOM'
    'address': {
        'address': 'NewYork'
    }
}
ac = AccountSerializer(data=data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that's not the answer what I want. Would you please read the question more carefully. What i want to know is: 1. instant the AccountSerializer first without any data arguments `ac = AccountSerializer()` 2. After that, how can I set the attribute value on it, like `ac.name = "TOM"`. Can you understand what I mean? Thanks

Comment: Well, serializers contain dictionaries, but are not a dictionary, so i am not sure if that is possible.

Comment: Yes. That's my concern. I haven't found out any approach to update the serializer after it's instanced. Anyway, thanks so much for your reply indeed.